# Transpose a Python Dataframe according many variables

Tags: python, pandas, sas, reshape, transpose

I have a Dataframe from one file, i have products and price together. I have on file per day who registered all the products bought by customer. So the length of columns depends of the biggest number of product bought by One client. On the start, i have a file like that :

```
date     conv   product      Prices 
01/2016 'part ' A|B|C|E|F 15|20|30|40|50 
01/2016 'Pro'   D|B       10|10
```

Then i split that file by "|", and after that i have 5 columns on my new df. beacause the biggest number of product bought by One client for that day is equal 5.

The Final DataFrame give :

```
Date     Conv    Product_1 product_2 ... product_n  price_1  price_2 ... price_n
01/2016  'Part'        A        B           C            15      20          30 
01/2016  'Pro'         B        D           C            10      10          20 
02/2016  'Part'        E        A           B            25      5           10
```

I would like to transpose Variables "Product_1 ...product_n" and "price 1 ... price_n". And obtain a new df :

```
Date      Conv   Product   price 
01/2016  'Part'     A        15
01/2016  'Part'     B        20
01/2016  'Part'     C        30
01/2016  'Pro'      B        10
01/2016  'Pro'      D        10
01/2016  'Pro'      C        20
02/2016  'Part'     E        25
02/2016  'Part'     A         5
02/2016  'Part'     B        10
```

The difficulty is on transpose variable and copy the variable Date and conv.

I think with `SAS` we can obtain that with the code :

```
Proc transpose ; 
Data = DF;
VAR product_1-product_4 price1_price_4;
BY Date Conv;
COPY Date Conv;
```

But on Python I don't find an equivalent.

Someone Know how can I do please ?

I try with : `df.transpose`

But it's not the result that I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first select columns by `list` comprehension with `startswith` and then use `pd.lreshape`:

```
prods = ([col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('product_')])
prices = ([col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('price_')])

print (prods)
['product_1', 'product_2', 'product_n']
print (prices)
['price_1', 'price_2', 'price_n']

df1 = pd.lreshape(df, {'product' : prods, 'price' : prices}) 
print (df1)
     Conv     Date  price product
0  'Part'  01/2016     15       A
1   'Pro'  01/2016     10       B
2  'Part'  02/2016     25       E
3  'Part'  01/2016     20       B
4   'Pro'  01/2016     10       D
5  'Part'  02/2016      5       A
6  'Part'  01/2016     30       C
7   'Pro'  01/2016     20       C
8  'Part'  02/2016     10       B
```

EDIT by more specify question:

```
#new df1 from column product
df1 = (df['product'].str.split('|', expand=True))
#add prod_ to column names
prods = df1.columns = ['prod_' + str(col) for col in df1.columns] 

#new df2 from column Prices
df2 = (df['Prices'].str.split('|', expand=True))
#add part_ to column names
prices = df2.columns = ['part_' + str(col) for col in df2.columns]

#join all together
df3 = (pd.concat([df[['date','conv']], df1, df2], axis=1))

#reshape
print (pd.lreshape(df3, {'product' : prods, 'price' : prices}))
     conv     date price product
0  'part'  01/2016    15       A
1   'pro'  01/2016    10       D
2  'part'  01/2016    20       B
3   'pro'  01/2016    10       B
4  'part'  01/2016    30       C
5  'part'  01/2016    40       E
6  'part'  01/2016    50       F
```

Another solution with `join`:

```
#create dataframe and stack, drop level of multiindex
s1 = (df['product'].str.split('|', expand=True)).stack()
s1.index = s1.index.droplevel(-1)
s1.name = 'product'

s2 = (df['Prices'].str.split('|', expand=True)).stack()
s2.index = s2.index.droplevel(-1)
s2.name = 'price'

#remove original columns    
df = df.drop(['product','Prices'], axis=1)

#join series to dataframe    
df1 = (df.join(s1).reset_index(drop=True))
df2 = (df.join(s2).reset_index(drop=True))

#join all togehter
print (pd.concat([df1, df2[['price']]], axis=1))
      date    conv product price
0  01/2016  'part'       A    15
1  01/2016  'part'       B    20
2  01/2016  'part'       C    30
3  01/2016  'part'       E    40
4  01/2016  'part'       F    50
5  01/2016   'pro'       D    10
6  01/2016   'pro'       B    10
```

**Timings**:

```
In [598]: %timeit (a(df))
100 loops, best of 3: 10.6 ms per loop

In [599]: %timeit (b(df_a))
100 loops, best of 3: 14.1 ms per loop
```

**Code for timings**:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: '01/2016', 1: '01/2016'}, 
                   'conv': {0: "'part'", 1: "'pro'"}, 
                   'Prices': {0: '15|20|30|40|50', 1: '10|10'}, 
                   'product': {0: 'A|B|C|E|F', 1: 'D|B'}}, 
                    columns =['date','conv','product','Prices'])
```

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

print (df)
df_a = df.copy()

def a(df):
    df1 = (df['product'].str.split('|', expand=True))
    prods = df1.columns = ['prod_' + str(col) for col in df1.columns] 

    df2 = (df['Prices'].str.split('|', expand=True))
    prices = df2.columns = ['part_' + str(col) for col in df2.columns]

    df3 = (pd.concat([df[['date','conv']], df1, df2], axis=1))

    return (pd.lreshape(df3, {'product' : prods, 'price' : prices}))


def b(df):
    s1 = (df['product'].str.split('|', expand=True)).stack()
    s1.index = s1.index.droplevel(-1)
    s1.name = 'product'

    s2 = (df['Prices'].str.split('|', expand=True)).stack()
    s2.index = s2.index.droplevel(-1)
    s2.name = 'price'

    df = df.drop(['product','Prices'], axis=1)

    df1 = (df.join(s1).reset_index(drop=True))
    df2 = (df.join(s2).reset_index(drop=True))

    return (pd.concat([df1, df2[['price']]], axis=1))

print (a(df))    
print (b(df_a))
```

EDIT:

[`lreshape`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape.py#L857) is now undocumented, but is possible in future will by removed ([with pd.wide_to_long too](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15003#issuecomment-324625271)).

Possible solution is merging all 3 functions to one - maybe `melt`, but now it is not implementated. Maybe in some new version of pandas. Then my answer will be updated.

Comment: Thanks Jezrael,

I try your code, and i forgot to specify, that the columns are not the same length. It depends of the number of product on a basket.

So Python display that error : 

All column lists must be same length

Comment: So some columns e.g. `price_2` is missing?

Comment: Yes price_2 price_3...Price_n same things for product

Comment: Ok, so if I select columns, I get something like: `['product_1', 'product_2', 'product_3', 'product_n']
['price_1', 'price_2', 'price_n']` ? (no `price_3`) Columns have same structure, only difference in last number? How many is columns for each category?

Comment: No, i have product_1 until product_n , on my file i have 24 columns but on an other file i have 30 columns. Like i said, it depends of how many products bought on a basket  by someone.

Comment: Can you add sample of DataFrame, which produce error? I dont understand. Do you have all products in one file and in other prices? Or in one file are products and prices together?

Comment: In one file, i have products and price together. I have on file per day who registered all the products bought by customer. 

So the length of columns depends of the biggest number of product bought by One client.

On the start, i have a file like that : 

date         conv   product             Prices 
01/2016   'part '    A|B|C|E|F     15|20|30|40|50
01/2016    'Pro'     D|B               10|10

Then i split that file by "|", and after that i have 5 columns on my new df. beacause the biggest number of product bought by One client for that day is equal 5.

Comment: I add two possible solutions, please check it.